# Replace [] with () in a String

Tags: java, regex

How can I change a String like this:

```
[a,b,c]
```

to this:

```
(a,b,c)
```

I want to use Java's regular expressions.

Comment: Im using but dont know if its nice option Arrays.toString(enum).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")")

Comment: It will help us to know what you have tried so far. Any code (or at least the regular expressions you may have tried so far).

Comment: Im a fool with regexp in the previous comment you have my current code =(

Comment: Sorry about that - Wasn't there when I commented.

Answer (score 8):

If your problem is just these parentheses, something like this could suffice:

```
s.replaceAll("\\[", "(").replaceAll("\\]", ")")
```

Comment: Ok I tougth that way could be low optimized but I'll use it. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how much more optimized it gets - it's a straight-forward basic search/replace operation (lack of pattern matching makes it trivial).

Comment: in this case, you are actually using a kind of shortcut method to regex through the string object.  I may be using the wrong words to say it, but you get the idea.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: @Bueller The only problem is that the standard regular expression support in Java *is painful* for a "basic task" like this. In particular there is no ability to supply conditional *replacement rules* thus making two regular expression replacements easier...

Answer (score 3):

Actualy you can do this by invoking replaceAll once

```
"[a, b, c]".replaceAll("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]", "($1)");
```